# understand the logic between Vim script "if" statement and filetype command

Tags: vimscript

I have a following very simple `.vimrc` file based on an example in [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim2/practical-vim-second-edition) book:

```
set nocompatible
set hidden
if has("autocmd")
  filetype on
  autocmd FileType sh setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
endif
```

As I understand, if file is a shell script file, then `FileType` event happens, if condition is started and `setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab` command is executed? However, what is the point of keeping the `filetype on`([enables file type detection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetypes)) inside the `if` statement? Shouldn't this be outside and before the `if` statement?

Comment: `:filetype` needs a version of Vim compiled with `autocmd` to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, what is the point of keeping the filetype on(enables file type detection) inside the if statement? Shouldn't this be outside and before the if statement?

The point is to avoid parse errors if `filetype` isn't available.

`if(has("autocmd"))` is testing if the version of vim parsing the `.vimrc` was *compiled with* autocommand support. [`:filetype` isn't available unless autocommand support has been compiled in](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d29459baa61819e59961804ed258efac5733ec70/src/ex_docmd.c#L410), so trying to call it outside the body of that if statement on those version of vim would produce errors.